# looking for a pattern in iis files with logparser s

Tags: iis, iis-6, sql, log-files, logparser

I am looking to extract from iis 
when a certain user session indicated here by aspnetsessionid times out prior to 10 minutes session timeout I have set on this application.

I am trying to parse iis logs and I am not sure how to take each sessionid and count how many minutes it lasted.

After I have this first part solved, I will look for which of the sessions ended with a call to the page timeout.aspx although it would be nice to specify this in one query.

I am trying to work on this query

```
SELECT  
TO_STRING(time, 'm') as mins,
    EXTRACT_TOKEN(EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs(Cookie), 1, 'ASP.NET_SessionId='), 0, ';+__ut') as    ASPNETSESSIONID From C:\logs\ex11*.log
GROUP BY ASPNETSESSIONID, mins
```

Here is an example of my log file instance I am trying to catch

```
Line Number Date    Time    Client-IP   Server IP   Server Port Request Verb    Request URI, ASPNETSessionID
255 4/1/2011    19:40:55    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /webpage.aspx   1234567890
256 4/1/2011    19:40:55    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /jscript/SessionTimeout/SessionTimeout.js   1234567890
257 4/1/2011    19:40:58    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /VerifySession.aspx 1234567890
260 4/1/2011    19:41:04    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /Formle.aspx    1234567890
261 4/1/2011    19:41:04    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /jscript/SessionTimeout/SessionTimeout.js   1234567890
263 4/1/2011    19:41:05    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /VerifySession.aspx 1234567890
265 4/1/2011    19:41:10    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /FormItemsTable.aspx    1234567890
266 4/1/2011    19:41:10    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /FormRecord.aspx    1234567890
267 4/1/2011    19:41:10    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /jscript/SessionTimeout/SessionTimeout.js   1234567890
268 4/1/2011    19:41:12    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /VerifySession.aspx 1234567890
273 4/1/2011    19:41:23    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /FormRd.aspx    1234567890
274 4/1/2011    19:41:23    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /jscript/SessionTimeout/SessionTimeout.js   1234567890
275 4/1/2011    19:41:25    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 POST    /VerifySession.aspx 1234567890
276 4/1/2011    19:41:25    222.222.22.22   111.11.111.11   443 GET /Timeout.aspx   1234567890
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539229/whiting-a-group-by-query-for-logparser-to-look-for-a-pattern/5540840#5540840

import the data into db, then query

```
SELECT * from ((SELECT MAX(LocalDateTime) FROM dpo.importtable AS [initial] WHERE sessionid = raw_data.sessionid) - (SELECT MIN(LocalDateTime) FROM dpo.importtable AS [initial] WHERE sessionid = raw_data.sessionid) as diff) as g where diff < CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:00.000' AS datetime)
```